# Can I format an unknown amount of strings comma separated with three strings on each line?

Tags: java, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I have looked for the past hour at least but to no avail. I'm writing a text based adventure game and I have an ArrayList storing my inventory. I am currently working on a "displayInventory" method which simply prints the inventory to console.

```
public void displayInventory()  
{                   
    
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("Inventory: \n");


    String format = ("%s, %s, %s %n"); 
    
    for (int i=0; i< inventory.size(); i++)
    {
        
        result.append(inventory.get(i));
    }
        
    //String result = String.join("," inventory);
    
    
    System.out.format(format, result.toString());;
}
```

Now initially my issue was figuring out how to use it with StringBuilder but now I sort of have that down. But I've run into the issue where I've set the format to three strings(items from inventory) to be printed to each line. After testing it with only two items I get the errors below (which makes sense).

```
Inventory: 
Small BottleLarge Bottle, Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2688)
at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
at wonderland/gameObjects.Player.displayInventory(Player.java:41)
at wonderland/gameObjects.Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

Do I need to set up some sort of check to see if there is a multiple of three items in the players inventory and have different print statements/formats if not? Is there a way to format an unknown amount (or at least a varying amount) of strings?

The player could pick three items up, use one, then pick up another two. I need some way of displaying the varying amount of items that could be in their inventory.

I hate asking questions on SO because they almost always get declared duplicates, despite no case being identical. So I was really hesitant but couldn't take the head trauma any longer. Thank you in advance for any and all help/answers.

Comment: Perhaps a better question to ask would be: How do I join an arbitrary number of strings together, separated by a comma and a space?

Comment: And why did you reject your `String.join` solution -- that's the right way to do it.

Comment: I have 17 items currently and I started thinking about how long the string would be and how i could format it better. You are right that it worked but I was hoping i could find a way to have three items per line to make it cleaner i guess.

Comment: You certainly can do that, but you'll need to do some programming to do it -- write a loop that goes through every three items, and handle the remainder somehow.

Comment: I assumed, maybe naively, that i could. I am currently working on a loop to do just that but I am just not sure how exactly I am going to do it. Thought maybe someone could point me in the right direction I suppose.

Comment: So you are really after some kind of word wrap feature for console output? The only ones I have seen were hand coded.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, (inventory.size() + 2) / 3) .mapToObj(i -> inventory.subList(i * 3, Math.min((i + 1) * 3, inventory.size())).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "", ", "))) .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))`. Prints an ugly comma in the end, though, we will need to fix that.

Comment: @OleV.V. `IntStream.range(0, (inventory.size() + 2) / 3)
                .mapToObj(i -> String.join(", ", inventory.subList(i * 3, Math.min((i + 1) * 3, inventory.size()))))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));`

Comment: @chptr-one Nice! That gives output that at least I like. Or `IntStream.range(0, (inventory.size() + 2) / 3) .mapToObj(i -> inventory.subList(i * 3, Math.min((i + 1) * 3, inventory.size())).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))) .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n"))` if we want comma after each line except the last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `String.join()` you describe in the comments, you get this:

```
List<String> inventory = List.of(
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
    "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q");

public void displayInventory()  {                   
    System.out.println("Inventory:");
    for (int i = 0, size = inventory.size(); i < size; i += 3)
        System.out.println(String.join(", ",
            inventory.subList(i, Math.min(i + 3, size))));
}
```

and

```
displayInentory();
```

output:

```
Inventory:
A, B, C
D, E, F
G, H, I
J, K, L
M, N, O
P, Q
```

Comment: Combining `List.subList` and `String.join` is a creative way to append the comma conditionally.   Thanks for sharing!

Comment: So I really like both answers provided but for the sake of simplicity I am going to accept this answer. I believe it to be more concise and it gets the job done. However i would like it noted that the other answer provided has a very SMALL benefit over this one in that it  can append a comma on the third item in each line if there are more items after.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't considered that you may want to keep the trailing commas.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to set up some sort of check to see if there is a multiple of three items in the players inventory and have different print statements/formats if not? Is there a way to format an unknown amount (or at least a varying amount) of strings?

Yes, or use a looping method as described in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74623913/3196753).  This is because `PrintStream.format()` doesn't allow any unused variables.

Below is and adaptation of "check[ing] to see if there is a multiple of three items in the players inventory" by manipulating the format string.

```
List inventory = List.of("Shovel", "Dirt", "Magazine", "Marble", "Orange", "Knife", "Popsicle");

StringBuilder format = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        // first item, prepend "Inventory:"
        format.append("Inventory:%n%s");
    } else if(i == inventory.size() -1) {
        // last item, don't prepend or append
        format.append("%s");
    } else if(i % 3 == 2) {
        // third item, append newline
        format.append("%s%n");
    } else if(i < inventory.size() -1) {
        // 1st or 2nd item, append comma and space
        format.append("%s, ");
    }
}

System.out.println("Format: \n" + format + "\n");
System.out.format(format.toString(), inventory.toArray());;
```

Output:

```
Format: 
Inventory:%n%s%s, %s%n%s, %s, %s%n%s

Inventory:
ShovelDirt, Magazine
Marble, Orange, Knife
Popsicle
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is what I thought I was going to have to do but couldn't figure it out. However, I have accepted the other answer due to its simplicity. Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: Another downside to this solution is that it will not handle inventory items with special characters such as `%n`, `%s` properly.  I'm not sure if this would ever occur with inventory items specifically, but it's another downside to utilizing the `.format(...)` API, or any API that performs blind substitution.